# Como puedo insertar datos en 2 tablas - PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

actualmente me encuentro realizando un practica de un pequeño blog con php y sql y necesito insertar datos en 2 tablas al mismo tiempo, por ejemplo al crear un nuevo post seleccionó sus categorías de dicho post y que estas se muestren en una tabla distinta llamada entradas.

Estas son las 3 tablas que tengo creadas, en POSTS se almacena todos los datos de las publicaciones y en CATEGORIAS se almacena todos los datos de las categorías.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**TABLA: POST**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**TABLA: CATEGORIAS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces mi duda es de como puedo hacer que se inserte los datos a la tabla entradas y se almacenen las ID de las publicaciones y las ID'S de las categorías seleccionadas. Como por ejemplo en este caso la publicación "El océano" tiene de categoría "naturaleza".

**Ejemplo de la tabla entradas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODIGO: db.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connect.php');

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}


function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}


function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

        $i = 0;
                foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
               $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }

function create($table, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    $id = $stmt->insert_id;
    return $id;
    
}

function update($table, $id, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE id=?";
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function delete($table, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=?";
      
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}
```

CODIGO: posts.php

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validatePost.php');

$table = 'posts';
$categorias = selectAll('categorias');

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$title = '';
$body = '';

$posts = selectAll($table);

    
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = "../../images/" . $image_name;
        
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
        if ($result){
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "¡Algo fallo al subir la imagen!");
        }
        
        
    } else {
      array_push($errors, "¡Necesitas subir una imagen!");
    }
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Anime creado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];

    }


if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Anime eliminado correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Anime actualizado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
}
} 
?>
```

CODIGO: categorias.php

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/database/db.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/helpers/validateCategoria.php');

$table = 'categorias';

$errors = array();
$id = '';
$name = '';
$body = '';
$topic_id = '';

$categorias = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $errors = validateCategoria($_POST);
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria creada correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];

    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria eliminada correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Categoria actualizada correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/categorias/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];

}
} 
?>
```

Comment: El codigo que agregaste está demás. Lo que importa, es como estás intentando tú hacer esto. Ahora mismo estás preguntando como hacerlo, lo que no es admitido sin mostrar tus intentos de ello. Por otro lado, la relación de tablas, es lo que importará en tu caso.

Comment: @Excorpion | El problema es que no se como hacerlo, he investigado de distintas maneras y me quede sin opciones por eso recurrí a intentar preguntar por aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es que cuando insertes un registro en la tabla **post** automáticamente se inserte un registro en la tabla **entradas**, te recomendaría utilizar un procedimiento almacenado donde le mandes los argumentos necesarios para la creación de un post la sintaxis seria parecida a

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `postEntrada`(
in tituloPost varchar(150),
in image varchar(150), #aquí depende cuanta longitud le diste a tu campo
in idCategoria integer #Categoria seleccionada por el autor
)
BEGIN

    declare lastPost integer;

    start transaction;
        insert into post() Values(null, tituloPost, image);
        select id from post order by id desc limit 1 into lastPost; # obtengo ultimo registro creado
        insert into entradas() values(null, lastPost, idCategoria); #Se inseta registro con post creado y categoria seleccionada por autor
    commit;

END
```

y con php solo la llamas con la sentencia `call postEntrada("Titulo", "Ruta imagen", idCategoria);`